# How do I debug into *.a libraries with VS Code?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, gdb, mingw

When I press F11 after hitting a breakpoint to step into the library function it appears correctly in the call stack window, but the source file is not found. When I click on the function name in the call stack VS code says "The editor could not be opened because the file was not found". However, in this view (1:st image) I can see the expected path and I've tried to add this to sourceFileMap in my launch.json (2:nd image), but so far no luck. How do I specify the source file? I'm using mingw and gdb.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have the source for these libraries? Did you build them yourself? The debugger depends on symbol tables that may not be present if these are externally built, so they are basically black boxes unless you're really good at reading assembly.

Comment: The library was built on a build server with symbols and I have the sources. I can step into them with IAR embedded workbench.

Comment: I'm not sure the symbol tables are portable between compilers. If you build with compiler X, you generally must debug with compiler X's debugger as well.